# Parameterized SQL Statements

Tags: sql-server, powershell, parameterized-query

I'm trying to use a simple insert query to fill a SQL table. Currently, my script creates the query by concatenating strings but I would like to parameterize the query in order to avoid getting the following error:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "String or binary data would be truncated.

Currently I am setting up my connection, like so:

```psh
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$ConnectionString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDatabase;Integrated  Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"
$conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString 
$conn.Open()
```

and my un-parameterized query looks like this:

```psh
$commandText = "INSERT INTO Servers (Name, OS, Notes, OSOwner) VALUES('$myvm', '$operatingSystem', '$desc', '$owner')"
$command = $conn.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $commandText
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I've seen people discuss different solutions to this in other posts but I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterization won't remove the problem, it'll just move it to a different section of code.

Your `Servers` table is designed such that one or more of the fields is smaller than the value you're attempting to insert into it. Fix that first - you've made an incorrect assumption about your data sizes.

Comment: Hmm...thats what I thought originally, but didn't spot any data that looked truncated out of the 2,000 some rows. I'll look a bit closer, thanks man.

Comment: To debug, output `$commandtext`, then copy & paste it into SSMS. It should throw the same error.

Answer (score 1):

alroc is correct in that the error you're seeing is related to data sizes; to provide an answer on parameterisation, here's what I would suggest:

```
function execSQL($sqlQuery) {

try {
    $sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$SqlServer; Database=$sqlDB; Application Name=$appName; Trusted_Connection=True"
    $sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 60
    $sqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlQuery
    $sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection
    $sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

}
catch [system.exception] {
    "$_ `r`nSQL Servername: $SqlServer" #send to log file
}
finally {
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    $SqlConnection.Dispose()
}

}


$appName = "brief description of what the SQL connection is being used for"

$sqlQuery = @"
INSERT INTO Servers (Name, OS, Notes, OSOwner) 
VALUES(@myvm, @operatingSystem, @desc, @owner)
"@

$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myvm", $myvm) | Out-Null
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operatingSystem", $operatingSystem) | Out-Null
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", $desc) | Out-Null
$sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner", $owner) | Out-Null

execSQL $sqlQuery
```

Supplying an application name in the connection string helps your DBA to understand what the connection is if they're auditing connections. Wrapping the SQL stuff in a try/catch/finally construct allows us to catch errors but more importantly, even if an error is thrown, the SQL connection will be tidied up.